# Multiple Calculations in SQL SELECT Query from Multiple Tables using Where?

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 Tables,  Inventory And Transactions,  Inventory Contains details about the Inventory Item.  Transactions is linked via PK to record goods in / goods out quantities.

I am attempting to get a table that not only displays the Inventory Details,  But also the Transaction Totals for each Inventory Row.

Currently What I am working with is:

```
SELECT Inventory.InvID,
sum(case when ITT.TransactionTypeName = 'GoodsIn' then Quantity else 0 end) As Goods_In
sum(case when ITT.TransactionTypeName = 'GoodsOut' then Quantity else 0 end) As Goods_Out
FROM
Inventory
INNER JOIN Transactions As IT ON Inventory.InvID = IT.InvID
INNER JOIN TransactionType AS ITT ON IT.TransactionType = ITT.TransactionTypeID
GROUP BY ITT.TransactionTypeName
```

I found this on Stack Overflow from another post and through various tests and issues cannot seem to get it to provide the correct Data.

With this I have a few questions:

- Is it possible to perform calculations in a query such as Above?
- Can someone Point me in the right direction to solve this particular Query?
- Am I using the Correct Join for this task? and/or is a Union Required?

**Edit**

Through further Testing I did get this working and It was my own Silly mistake.  I had to Group it By a Common Field (in this case Inventory.InvID)

**Edit2**

This does not however appear to return values that have no Transactions (e.g Empty or Unchecked items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I Basically answered Part of my own question (That this is indeed Possible),  I was getting an Error

Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Inventory.InvID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by   0.000 sec

This led me to test out the Group By Clause.  I determined that I needed to use a Common Field across the Joined tables and this resulted in me getting the correct data.